# How to get the Podio APP response detail level mini, micro or short?

Tags: podio

At many place in the Podio API documentation, it seems that you can specify the level of details that will be in the response: Full/Short/Mini/Micro. For example in the Get App call https://developers.podio.com/doc/applications/get-app-22349

However there is not details on how to specify the level of request in the http request... what is the parameter name/values?

I tried:

- https://api.podio.com/app/?fields=app.view(micro)
- https://api.podio.com/app/?fields=micro

but both responses have the same level of details: full

**EDIT:**
It appears that the 'micro' view is not working as explain in the documentation. Where are the 'mini' view is matching the doc. See below the list of the keys returned for each view.

**View Mini:**

[image]

**View Micro:**

[image]

Comment: any update from the podio team on this issue?

Comment: some of Podio documentation pages are not up to date. Sorry. We will try to fix it, but can't promise anything.

Comment: @Pavlo-Podio any update?

Comment: Tried the query parameter "view=mini" for "item_filter" query (Post method so the view parameter is in the json body) and it doesn't work.

Comment: Please raise another question, so answers will not overlap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this one: **?view=micro**

```
curl -H "Authorization: OAuth2 <auth_token>"   
"https://api.podio.com/app/<app_id>?view=micro"
```

Comment: Not working for the "item_filter" query (Post method so the view parameter is in the json body). Could you update your answer for the case of item_filter query?

Comment: To me `&fields=items.view(micro)` and `&fields=items.view(full)` change behaviour. But looks like using the name of a custom view (Team view, not Private view) doesn't affect anything and is not possible to choose what fields are returned by the API.