# Podio dotnet client library filter items with minimum field return

Tags: c#, podio

I am using Podio dot net client library, I would like to get items in an app (which I am able to) but this returned item with all the fields. I would like the response to only return certain fields. How can I achieve this?

This is what i have got so far:

```
PodioCollection<PodioAPI.Models.Item> podioCollection =podio.ItemService.FilterItems(Settings.Default.PodioAppId) // PodioAppId is the appID.
```

This return items with all the fields in it, I would like to restrict the result set to only contain certain fields or return a micro view as mention here

[How to get the Podio APP response detail level mini, micro or short?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40131817/how-to-get-the-podio-app-response-detail-level-mini-micro-or-short)

I downloaded the source of dot net library and modified the filter funtions to take my query string. And then i tried passing the following query strings

**Edit:**

```
?fields=app.view(full)

?fields=app.view(micro)

?fields=app.view(mini)

?fields=items.view(full)

?fields=items.view(micro)
```

`**?fields=items.view(mini)**`

for the **mini items** view I saw that no fields are being returned but for everyother call it sends back all the fields. Neither of them is what I am after.

```
 public async Task<PodioCollection<Item>> FilterItems(int appId, FilterOptions filterOptions, bool includeFiles = false, string queryString = null)
        {
            filterOptions.Limit = filterOptions.Limit == 0 ? 30 : filterOptions.Limit;
            string url = string.Format("/item/app/{0}/filter/", appId);
            if (includeFiles)
            {
                url = url + "?fields=items.fields(files)";
            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(queryString))
            {
                url = url + queryString;
            }
            return await _podio.Post<PodioCollection<Item>>(url, filterOptions);
        }
```

Thanks

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in order to check exactly what you need

Comment: You should read [ask]. Also, we're not here to do code design for you. Please have a go yourself - and when you get stuck show your code - then we can help.

Comment: Very smart, may be you find something st away....

Answer (score 1):

You can use **fields** parameter for that.
Possible values were mentioned here: [Can podio's api filter item response with only a mini detail level for each item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41952268/can-podios-api-filter-item-response-with-only-a-mini-detail-level-for-each-item/41966103#comment71864451_41966103)

You should probably use `filterOptions` variable from `FilterItems` method: 
https://github.com/podio/podio-dotnet/blob/master/Source/Podio%20.NET/Services/ItemService.cs#L256-L264

For random app that I've tried this, for different items.view() I'm getting different number of fields/attributes returned.

```
fields=items.view(full)  => result['items'][0].length: 26 
fields=items.view(short) => result['items'][0].length: 19
fields=items.view(mini)  => result['items'][0].length: 10
fields=items.view(micro) => result['items'][0].length: 5
```

Comment: This is not working. Should I have to configure something in Podio

Comment: Can you please explain how it is not working, what you have tried and what results you got?

Comment: It's not clear what do you pass and where. Why can't you share modified filter function with examples of calls (with input and output)?

Comment: Just edited my question with the modified filter function. Please note that I am not passing includefiles to that function. I am passing the values as mentioned in the question and result doesnt change except for Mini where it doesnt return any fields at all.

Comment: Ok, can you please publish what is returned for different inputs? Could it be that your Podio app has only 1 field and that's why all of outputs works same?

Comment: The podio app has 72 fields, I wont be able to publish the details here. But except for the Mini rest gave back the same number of fields.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136409/discussion-between-pavlo-podio-and-snit80).